# How would you abbreviate Amount per Hour?

Tags: orthography

If I need the abbreviation of "Amount per Hour" to be used as a label/title, should it be:
"Amt/***Hr***" or "Amt/***hr***" or something else?

Comment: Amount is not a unit of measurement like hour, use an appropriate unit of measurement. Perhaps, US$/hr. Or, do you mean 'amount' in the sense of quantity?

Comment: I am referring to the case of "hour". Should is be lower case? Thanks

Comment: I would do "amt/h" or "amt/hr"

Comment: I often see mph or MPH for miles per hour.

Comment: ... But I don't often see the capital H in any other abbreviations.

Comment: u/hr. U for unit, which would be anything you want. You would have to provide some context, though, so your readers would know what you're talking about.

Comment: Rather than focusing on the "correct" capitalization of a non-standard term, it might be better to use the standard term. In the case of "amount/time" or "quantity/time", that term is "*rate*"; in your case where time is measured in hours, the nearly universal term is "*hourly rate*". The term more specifically applied in an employment or services context, it's typically "*wage*" (as in "*minimum wage*"). In a scientific context.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who are weighing in, but the Amount part is just an example. I am more interested in the capitalization instead of the actual wording. And this needs to be abbreviated due to spacing constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most common ways to handle capitalization in a text head or subhead or in a table or chart column head are "title case" and "sentence case." In standard title case, you capitalize each word (or abbreviated word) unless it is an article (*a* or *the*) or a short preposition (how short a preposition varies from one style guide to another, and some specify that all prepositions be lowercased). In sentence case, only the first word of the head plus any proper names or acronyms are capitalized.

Normally these rules apply to abbreviated words just as they do to whole words. So if you were running other heads, subheads, or table column heads in title case, you would use "Amount per Hour" (*per* being a three-letter preposition) spelled out or "Amt/Hr" abbreviated. On the other hand, if you were running other heads, subheads, or table column heads in sentence case, you would use "Amount per hour" spelled out or "Amt/hr" abbreviated.

The point of these rules is to achieve cosmetic consistency throughout a book or article; they are not based on any deep understanding of how language works, nor are they designed to compete with other rules for world domination. Internal consistency—that's all they're about.

Answer (score 1):

If it is for a label or title, as you say, then do not abbreviate. Especially do not abbreviate using your own, invented abbreviation for your own, invented unit.

Use a label or title of *Amount/Time* or *Bushels/Hour*, if you are measuring the amount in bushels. (*Amount* is not a unit; *hour* is a unit, as is *bushel*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the Amount part is just an example. I am more interested in the capitalization instead of the actual wording. And this needs to be abbreviated due to spacing constraints.

Comment: Capitalization is purely a matter of style, and of conventions for the particular context.